# Make menu stay on top but not when scrolling down for side scroll website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a website that scrolls to the side and I was using fixed position to keep menu on top, but I realize when I scroll down, the menu will also scroll down. I'm wondering if there's a way to keep the menu on top when I scroll to the side, but it doesn't go down when I scroll down.

So I tried using absolute position relative to body, but that doesn't keep the menu on top when I side scroll.

```
#menu
{   
background          : url(images/banner5.gif) no-repeat;
height              : 60px;
margin-top          : 20px;
position            : absolute; 
left                : 450px;
}

#menuFloat li
{   
display             : inline;
float               : left; 
padding             : 8px 20px 0px 30px;
}

#menuFloat li a
{   
    color               : #9d0c10;
    font-family         : Erato;
    font-size           : 12pt;
    font-style          : italic;
    text-decoration     : none; 
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#menuFloat a").bind("click",function(event){ event.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");
   $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left, scrollTop:    $(target).offset().top }, 1200);
 }); });
```

---

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="menuFloat">
        <li><a class="nav1" href="#nav1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav2" href="#nav2">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav3" href="#nav3">Members</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav4" href="#nav4">Events</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav5" href="#nav5">Media</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav6" href="#nav6">Contact Us</a></li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

The first part is the CSS for the menu, second part is jquery code for how it can slide horizontally, and third part is html for the menu.

If you're confused of my problem, check here: http://permika-montreal.tk/new.php
When you scroll down, you'll see the menu does too and I'd like that not to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here

```
#menu
{   
background          : url(images/banner5.gif) no-repeat;
height              : 60px;
top                 : 20px;
position            : absolute; 
left                : 50px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var lastScrollLeft = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
    if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
        console.log('scroll x');
        lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
        $("#menu").css("left", lastScrollLeft+50);

    }
});   

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by updating the `left` CSS property whenever the user scrolls horizontally using JavaScript/jQuery.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9423822/1718121

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var x = $(this).scrollLeft();
  $("#menu").css("left", x + offset); //Change offset to be the default margin-left of your menu.
}
```

Comment: thanks, but can you give the html code for that solution? I'm not quite sure what each id does for that solution

Comment: @user977151 It looks like only the `$(window).scroll` part is really relevant. `el` would probably be your #menu. See my updated post.

Comment: Btw this is used when menu's position is fixed? What about if I want to use absolute position since mobile browsers have problems with fixed?

Comment: @user977151 The position should not be fixed because you don't want the menu to be vertically fixed.